# If lidar is used underwater, would passing through a turbulent surface into a pocket of air (e.g. a "moon pool") distort the resultant image at all?

Tags: laser, measurements, turbulence, imaging

I have zero experience with lidar systems, but I *have* been under clear water and looked up at the interior/ceiling of an indoor pool, and even the slightest turbulence at the surface distorts what I see to a greater extent than anything I look at underwater.

I do realize that laser light is more coherent than regular visible light, which *might* make it less vulnerable to any refractive distortion through the water/air interface. So I put this question preferentially to anyone with practical experience with lidar: would there be any noticeable difference, however slight, in the "crispness" of the telemetry data between lidar reading (A) a surface completely submerged versus (B) a surface *beyond* the water/air interface?

Comment: Writing in all caps is a really quick way to make your question seem unprofessional.